# The Conjuction "nun da"

Tags: grammar, dialect

> ***Nun da*** wir auf der Tagung sind, können wir über das Problem sprechen.
>   *Now that we're here in the Meeting, we can talk about the problem.*

Can one just write it in this manner:

> Jetzt sind wir auf der Tagung. Wir können über das Problem sprechen.

Here's another sentence but this time with "***wo***":

> ***Da wo*** wir am Wochenende nach Oregon fahren, lass uns unseren Freund Gustav besuchen!
>   *Seeing that we're going to Oregon on the weekend, let's visit our friend Gustav!*

Is *"da nun"* used in formal registers or in informal registers?

Comment: I don't think your "Da wo" example is correct. Maybe drop the "wo"? (It's not like "Da, wo ich hinschlage, wächst kein Gras mehr")

Comment: shouldn't your final question be about *"Nun da"* ?, also what connection is between *"Da wo"* and *"Nun da"* except the da?

Comment: Is there a comma missing after "Nun"?

Comment: @Ingo ... I thought so too but if you see the comments in arne.b's answer you'll find a link that says you can leave it out. I would put it anyway and I think we should point out that there is NO conjunction "nun da"... there is the vague temporal adverb "nun" which means something like "now" and there is the subordinating conjunction "da" that means "as" or "that" here. The choice we have is to LEAVE the comma that would naturally be there.

Comment: @Emanuel exactly my thought. We could leave out the *Nun* completely and alternatively the sub-sentence *da wir auf der Tagung sind*. That we can do the latter makes a good enough case for the comma as far as I am concerned, so I would put it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use **nun da** exactly where I'd use *now that*. It can definitely be used in a formal setting. While it is not too high-brow, I would not use it when getting a haircut, for example.

> Nun da ich schon mal hier bin, könnten Sie auch gleich...

Interestingly, in informal settings I might be tempted to use **wo** (without da, "Wo ich schon mal hier bin..."), but this might be some regional thing (North/East).

**Da ... nun** seems to be usable in the same context as **nun da**, but note that the sentence subject goes between the two words

> Da wir nun auf der Tagung sind...

As for your question of splitting it into two unconnected sentences, yes, that is possible, but you lose the connection. This question seems unrelated to the German language -- consider the same thing in English: Would you consider it a useful alternative:

> Jetzt sind wir auf der Tagung. Wir können über das Problem sprechen.
>
> Now we are at the meeting. We can talk about the problem.

Re **da wo**: There is a region where **wo** is used as a relativ pronoun ("Die Leute, wo nicht richtig deutsch sprechen können"), but I am not sure "da wo" would be used there either.

The causal connection in your example is perfectly made clear with *da*, which you can use whenever you would use *as* for a causal connection in English

> *As we are going to Oregon...*
>
> Da wir nach Oregon fahren...

Comment: Shouldn't there be a comma after "nun"? It seems to me that the whole "da"-sentence is elaboration about the already indicated point in time "nun". The main sentence would work with "nun" alone.

Comment: @Emanuel It would not look out of place, but I do not think it has to be there. [Duden's rule 127](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma#K127) may apply.